# How to include multiple DNAs into a crystal structure

Tags: biophysics

I have a crystal structure (PDB 3OS1)that shows the interaction of PFV intasome with a substate DNA. I would like to replace the existing DNA in the intasome as well in the substrate with a longer sequences. What is the easiest way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then ask questions informed by what you have learned (ideally with references to reliable sources). You are also more likely to need to get a positive response if you provide more detail and background about what your are trying to accomplish — I'm not clear on whether you are trying manipulate actual crystals or a structure file. ——— Please also take the time to go through the [tour] and the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and then edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: Could you clarify? Why do you expect the protein to have the same structure with a different substrate DNA? And even if it is a reasonable assumption, you are going to have to edit the coordinates of the existing bases with those for different ones. Furthermore how do you imagine you can model additional bases? Your request for “the easiest way” to do it suggests you don’t realize what is involved. Do you?